# How to use android Livedata transformation

Tags: android, android-livedata

My view model class have one mutable live data

```
   private MutableLiveData<AccountListResponse> mAccountsResponse = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

and one network bound resource repository returns another live data

```
  public LiveData<Resource<AccountListResponse>> loadAccounts() {
    }
```

I want to map load accounts results to mAccountsResponse , in ui I only observing to mAccountsResponse

I tried

```
LiveData<Resource<AccountListResponse>> mCachedccounts;
mCachedccounts=new AccountListRepository().loadAccounts();
mAccountsResponse=Transformations.map(mCachedccounts,input -> {
            return input.data;
});
```

But its giving error no instance of type variable Y exist.

Comment: Are you sure input.data is returning an instance of AccountListResponse?

Comment: yes. When i changes toMutable live data to  LiveData<AccountListResponse> mAccountsResponse, the error gone. but changes only one time triggering.